# Java Swing elements sizing and positioning issue

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm creating a Java swing app and I'm having a real hard time getting elements positioned nicely.

How would I go about making the input boxes and combo boxes to say 30px high? Also, how would I go about making the right edge of all the text line up vertically and the left edge of all the input boxes line up vertically?

I have a main JPanel which is BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, and then I have 6 JPanels on the main JPanel. These 6 JPanels are set to BorderLayout and as you can see I have used WEST for the JLabels and EAST for the input fields.

Here's a snippet of how I'm creating the 1st panel which is on top of the main panel.

```
private JPanel getProtocolPanel() {

    protocolNumber.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
    protocolNumberInput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN));
    protocolNumber.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

    protocolPanel = new JPanel();
    protocolPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    protocolPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    protocolPanel.add(protocolNumber, BorderLayout.WEST);
    protocolPanel.add(protocolNumberInput, BorderLayout.EAST);

    return protocolPanel;
}
```

[image]

Let me know if there is a better way to do this type of layout.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that! I mean: don't hard-code pixels values in your UI. This is bad, there's generally no good reason for it, and it will render badly when used on a high-resolution monitor. It is better to trust Swing for determining the "right" size of components, although on rare occasions, you may have to help Swing a little bit.

Comment: By the way, this looks like a very ugly GUI, does it really have to look like that?

Comment: the borders are to help me figure out how things are being positioned. I will remove them once I have elements where I want. If I shouldn't use px then how should I get the JTextFields to not look so fricken huge and ugly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are either going to have to nest layouts inside each other, or use a more complex layout (Spring, GridBag, Mig), or both to get the desired effect.

Comment: hmmm, look for DefalutLayoutManager, for those numbers of JComponents is there GridBagLayout (+1)

Comment: I vote for `GridBagLayout`. Once you get a handle on the constraints you can create almost anything.

Comment: I went with gridbaglayout. Took a while to understand it, but it makes things much much easier.